# How to same time insert multiple same column in jsp and mysql

Tags: mysql, jsp

How to the same time insert multiple same columns in JSP and MySQL?

ex: MY MySQL have two column call NAME and URL, I want to same time insert(add) 3-time column, how can I do?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, and update your question then. In short: **show your code** (what have you tried so far).

Answer (score 0):

ITS Simple use this syntax

```
INSERT INTO tbl ( Col1, Col2) VALUES ( Value1, Value2 ), ( Value1, Value2 ), ( Value1, Value2 );
```

Comment: thank you,and I want to insert in jsp, how can I do?

Comment: and maybe 3 time or 6 time.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(Bean b : values){
insert into(col1, col2) values("+b.getValue+", "+b.getValue+");
```

}

you have to use loop on the values to insert for that